# SQL - Order of Values across Columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to find the order of values across 5 columns in Oracle SQL and enter that sequence into column 6.

```
Col_1, Col_2, Col_3, Col_4, Col_5, Col_6

0.2  , 0.1  , 0.6  , 0.4  , 0.3  , 21543
```

Alternatively, I could work with 5 output columns for each row where the value is the column name.

```
Col_1, Col_2, Col_3, Col_4, Col_5, Col_6, Col_7, Col_8, Col_9, Col_10

0.2  , 0.1  , 0.6  , 0.4  , 0.3  , Col_2, Col_1, Col_5, Col_4, Col_3
```

Any and all suggestions appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to unpivot the data, repivot, and extract the information:

```
select id, col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4, col_5,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then which end) as o1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then which end) as o2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then which end) as o3,
       max(case when seqnum = 4 then which end) as o4,
       max(case when seqnum = 5 then which end) as o5
from (select id, col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4, col_5,
             row_number() over (partition by id, col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4, col_5 order by val) as seqnum
      from ((select id, col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4, col_5, 'col_1' as which, col_1 as val from table t) union all
            (select id, col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4, col_5, 'col_2' as which, col_2 as val from table t) union all
            (select id, col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4, col_5, 'col_3' as which, col_3 as val from table t) union all
            (select id, col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4, col_5, 'col_4' as which, col_4 as val from table t) union all
           (select id, col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4, col_5, 'col_5' as which, col_5 as val from table t)
          ) t
     ) t
group by d, col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4, col_5;
```

This is less efficient than just doing the logic across a single row.  But if the table is not too big, performance should be ok.

EDIT:

If you assume that the five values are all different, you could do:

```
select col1, col2, col3, col4, col5,
       (case when col1 = val1 then 'col1'
             when col2 = val1 then 'col2'
             when col3 = val1 then 'col3'
             when col4 = val1 then 'col4'
             else 'col5'
        end) as which1,
       (case when col1 = val2 then 'col1'
             when col2 = val2 then 'col2'
             when col3 = val2 then 'col3'
             when col4 = val2 then 'col4'
             else 'col5'
        end) as which2,
       (case when col1 not in (val1, val2, val3, val4) then 'col1'
             when col2 not in (val1, val2, val3, val4) then 'col2'
             when col3 not in (val1, val2, val3, val4) then 'col3'
             when col4 not in (val1, val2, val3, val4) then 'col4'
             else 'col5'
        end) as which3,
       (case when col1 = val4 then 'col1'
             when col2 = val4 then 'col2'
             when col3 = val4 then 'col3'
             when col4 = val4 then 'col4'
             else 'col5'
        end) as which4,
       (case when col1 = val5 then 'col1'
             when col2 = val5 then 'col2'
             when col3 = val5 then 'col3'
             when col4 = val5 then 'col4'
             else 'col5'
        end)
from (select least(case when col1 > val1 then col1 else col2 end,
                   case when col2 > val1 then col1 else col1 end,
                   case when col3 > val1 then col1 else col1 end,
                   case when col4 > val1 then col1 else col1 end,
                   case when col5 > val1 then col1 else col1 end
                  ) as val2,
             least(case when col1 < val5 then col1 else col2 end,
                   case when col2 < val5 then col1 else col1 end,
                   case when col3 < val5 then col1 else col1 end,
                   case when col4 < val5 then col1 else col1 end,
                   case when col5 < val5 then col1 else col1 end
                  ) as val4
      from (select col1, col2, col3, col4, col5,
                   least(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) as val1,
                   greatest(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) as val5
            from table t
           ) t
     ) t
```

This gets way more complicated if the values can be `NULL` or duplicated.

Comment: Thanks Gordon.  The table has 700,000 rows so I'd be concerned about performance.  I'll code this up and take a look. Thanks

Comment: @BarJames . . . That shouldn't be so bad.  I'm pretty sure it will return before you could code all the `case` statements needed to get a "within-row" method to work.

Comment: So that worked a treat!  I used the first of the two where you've used UNION.  Thank you.